# Prove that if $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in[m,M]$, then $x$ can be written as $m+\mu (M-m)$ where $\mu\in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Prove that if $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in[m,M]$, then $x$ can be written as $m+\mu (M-m)$ where $\mu\in [0,1]$.

This is obviously a very intuitive result but I struggle to write a formal proof for it. I feel like I need to use completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ here or the continuity of linear function. Graphically, I suppose you can construct an algorithm to locate $\mu$ by keep replacing the right and left interval.

It would be great if I could see as many alternative proofs as I can in this thread.

Comment: A good strategy is to use a translation and a dilation to trnasform $[m,M]$ into an $[0,1]$.

To be more precise, $\frac{x-m}{M-m}\in \left[0,1\right]$. So $\mu=\frac{x-m}{M-m}\in[0,1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m\le x\le M\Rightarrow x=(1-\mu)m+\mu M$ for some $\mu\in [0,1].$ Then, $x=m+\mu(M-m).$

Remark: the first inplication follows by considering the function $\mu\mapsto (1-\mu)m+\mu M$ and using the intermediate value theorem for continuous real-valued functions on intervals.